# How to extract domain address from a links in python data frame and write them into new one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, url

I have an excel file that contains links and other information in different columns, I created a date frame where I left only a column with the links from the original Excel file. I need to get the domain addresses from the links.

I have tried the following:

```
import re
from tldextract import extract   #  pip install tldextract

df25=df[['Источник 1']]

def get_domain(url):    
    subdomain, domain, suffix = extract(url)
    ignored = ["www", "web"]
    if not subdomain or subdomain.lower() in ignored:
        return domain
    pat = r"^(?:{})\.".format("|".join(ignored))
    return re.sub(pat, "", subdomain)

df25.apply(get_domain)
```

The error is the following:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Most likely some element(s) of `df25` are neither string nor bytes-like object. Without further information, it's hard to find the exact problem... Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Tranbi now it works with df25, I have changed the brackets: df25=df[('Источник 1')]

Comment: @Tranbi but it does not work(the same error) if I add new dataframes like:

df25=df[('Источник 1')]
df26=df[('Источник 2')]

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't fix your problem, but may guide you to where the `TypeError` is raised.

Try adding a `try/except` in your function to catch which `url` is raising the `TypeError`.

```py
import re
from tldextract import extract   #  pip install tldextract

df25=df[['Источник 1']]

def get_domain(url):
    try:
        subdomain, domain, suffix = extract(url)
        ignored = ["www", "web"]
        if not subdomain or subdomain.lower() in ignored:
            return domain
        pat = r"^(?:{})\.".format("|".join(ignored))
        return re.sub(pat, "", subdomain)

    except TypeError:
        return url

some_data = df25.apply(get_domain)

# filter to rows where url didn't change
some_data.loc[some_data.eq(df25).all(axis="columns")]
```

Comment: now it works for df25. However, I still have an error if I try to apply this to df26 and df27 (other columns of source file). When I apply your code to them I receive a blank page. I guess it due to the fact that in df25  all rows in the columns are filled and there are gaps. Maybe you know what I can do about it?